# notifyDataSetChanged() not refreshing in gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, calendar, notifydatasetchanged

So I am trying to create a custom calendar from scratch and it still looks like a basic calendar.
I created my own `CustomAdapter` that implements `ArrayAdapter` so that it can change values automatically. This is what I got so far:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.aldos.calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by aldos on 11/13/2016.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context c;
    private String[] date ;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context,String[] objects) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
        this.c = context;
        date = objects;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return date.length;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,parent,false);
            textView = new TextView(c);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120,120));
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        }else{
            textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        textView.setText(date[position]);


        return textView;

    }
}
```

And also with this **Customadapter.java**

```
package com.example.aldos.calendar;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Calendar calen = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = Calendar.MONTH;
    String[] DateList ;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DateList = init();

        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,DateList);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void previous(View v){
        month--;
        DateList = changemonth(month);

        for(int i = 0; i < DateList.length;i++){
            Log.d("prev",""+ DateList[i]);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void next(View v){
        month--;
        DateList = changemonth(month);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private String[] init(){
        String[] DateList = new String[42];
        calen.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1); // first day of the month

        int date  = calen.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int month = calen.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = calen.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day = calen.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);


        DateList = BeforeMonth(DateList,day,month);

        int numdays = daysinamonth(month);
        int endmonth = numdays+day -1;
        int j = day-1;

        while(j < (numdays+day-1) ){
            DateList[j] = Integer.toString(calen.get(Calendar.DATE));
            calen.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
            j++;
        }

        int end = 1;
        while(endmonth <42){
            DateList[endmonth] = Integer.toString(end);
            endmonth++;
            end++;
        }

        return DateList;

    }

    private String[] changemonth(int month){
        calen.set(Calendar.YEAR,month,Calendar.DATE);
        return init();
    }

    //adds the days before the first day of the month to the string list
    private String[]  BeforeMonth(String[] d, int day, int month){
        int LastMo = daysinamonth( month-1); // know how many days in the last month 31 10-1
        //Log.d("bmon","the current month" + month + " last month days " + LastMo + " day " + day);
        switch (day){
            case 1: // sunday
                break;
            case 2: // monday
                d[0] = Integer.toString(LastMo);
                break;
            case 3: // tuesday
                d[0] = Integer.toString(LastMo-1);
                d[1] = Integer.toString(LastMo);
                break;
            case 4: // wednesday
                d[0] = Integer.toString(LastMo-2);
                d[1] = Integer.toString(LastMo-1);
                d[2] = Integer.toString(LastMo);
                break;
            case 5: // thursday
                d[0] = Integer.toString(LastMo-3);
                d[1] = Integer.toString(LastMo-2);
                d[2] = Integer.toString(LastMo-1);
                d[3] = Integer.toString(LastMo);
                break;
            case 6: //friday
                d[0] = Integer.toString(LastMo-4);
                d[1] = Integer.toString(LastMo-3);
                d[2] = Integer.toString(LastMo-2);
                d[3] = Integer.toString(LastMo-1);
                d[4] = Integer.toString(LastMo);
                break;
            case 7: //saturday
                d[0] = Integer.toString(LastMo-5);
                d[1] = Integer.toString(LastMo-4);
                d[2] = Integer.toString(LastMo-3);
                d[3] = Integer.toString(LastMo-2);
                d[4] = Integer.toString(LastMo-1);
                d[5] = Integer.toString(LastMo);
                break;
        }

        return d;
    }

    //check how many days are in each month
    private int daysinamonth(int month){
        switch (month){
            case 0: // January
                return 31;
            case 1: // February
                return 28;
            case 2: // March
                return 31;
            case 3: // April
                return 30;
            case 4: // May
                return 31;
            case 5: // June
                return 30;
            case 6: // July
                return 31;
            case 7: // August
                return 31;
            case 8: // Sept
                return 30;
            case 9: // Oct
                return 31;
            case 10: // Nov
                return 30;
            case 11: // Dec
                return 31;
            default:
                return 0;
        } // switch stmt

    }
}
```

The code will work fine, but when I clicked on my previous and next button (which uses `onClick = "previous"` and `onClick = "next"` ) nothing will happen. The values will not change. Anyone know why?

Notes that might help:

- I uses an array of strings in my `ArrayAdapter` instead of `ArrayList`.
- For the purposes of this question, you only need to look at `onCreate`, `previous` and my `adapters`. Most of the functions is to only determine my datelist array.
- The `notifyDataSetChanged` is in both the `previous` and `next` function only and they don't work.

I've been trying to find a question similar to mine but I can't find that actually works.
Thank you

Comment: are you sure that you are getting new values in init() callling from changemonth();

Comment: I think that it is because you return 0 always in `getItemId()`. try returning position at least.

Comment: you are creating new object for DateList every time but in adapter you have reference of old object which one you create initially at the time of adapter creation.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Code,You are not setting value again to the adapter,so set the adapter with the new values and notify.

```
 public void next(View v){
                month--;
                DateList = changemonth(month);
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,DateList);
                grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }



    public void previous(View v){
            month--;
            DateList = changemonth(month);

            for(int i = 0; i < DateList.length;i++){
                Log.d("prev",""+ DateList[i]);
            }
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,DateList);
                grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Make chages like this and check.